# Can we replace the ものか with ことか? And why?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

> その中間、デスクの前に『休め』の姿勢で立つシンは眉一つ動かさない。独断専行の数々と軍規違反。必要だったからしたこととはいえ、詰問も懲罰もむしろ当然のことだ。
>
> 違反の内容からして拘束くらいはされるだろうと思っていたが、今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**ものか**。
>
> 86 ─ エイティシックス ─ Ep.2 ─ ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント ─〈上〉 安里アサト

Is the bold ものか just a nominalizer instead of meaning "there's no way..." in this context? If so, can we replace it with ことか? If not, could you please explain why?

I've attached a [image: picture] of the whole text.

Comment: I wouldn’t replace it with こと, but again I wouldn’t use もの to begin with. This author has a peculiar style.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you for your opinion. So what would you use to express the idea in question?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence sounds weird to me.

> ? 今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**もの**か。

Replacing もの with こと only makes it worse.

> x 今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**こと**か。

This is because the の in 済んでいるの doesn’t expected to be matched with a fact but a reason or cause. I think もの sounds less bad because it is not impossible to understand the sentence as a shorthand version of the following, more complete sentence.

> 今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**ことによるもの**か。

Here, の can be read as something like "situation" and もの as "result," 扱いを測りかねていること being its cause.

You can use an expression that more directly indicates the reason or cause, of course.

> 今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**ため**か。

> 今のところ尋問程度で済んでいるのは、扱いを測りかねている**から**か。